# ASP.Net Web API high response time hosted in Azure

Tags: performance, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have a Web API which is a in Azure App Service under a P3V2 app service plan. Sometimes the response time is getting too high (more than 1 minute) and the app hangs. I've enabled the Auto scaling up to 5 instance which trigger when the response time is greater than 5 seconds.

But when i'm analyzing past data in when the failures happen, I found that the scale out does not help this issue. Reason, the same thing happens in multiple occasions but the API didn't hang.

Then I tried to find any metric related to this issue. I found the **Handle count** is getting high just before the API hangs. The following metrics also increase around the same time:

- Response time        - more than 1 min
- Http server errors   - high
- CPU time             - normal

These snapshot are taken at the same time range.

**Response time**

[image: Repsonse times]

**Handle count**

[image: Handle count]

After restarting the app service, the API works fine. When I don't it remains unresponsive.

Can anyone help to find the reason for this?

**Update 1 :**

Multiple apps are running in same app service plan. There are external dependencies between these apps. I'm using Azure storage, Azure service bus and Azure SQL database.

Also i've noticed that TCP Established is high

[image: TCP Established]

Another point i need to mention; when i'm monitoring **live metrics**, it was not receiving insights from the application when this hang happen.

Comment: This looks like there might be something wrong with your application. You should review the availability of external dependencies for the API, like data storage. Also, are you calling out to external services? If so, are you using `HttpClient`?

Comment: @rickvdbosch  yes, as i updated i'm using azure sql server, azure storage, service bus

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue with your code. like @rickvdbosch mentioned, check for your dependency timings like a database operation, service bus write operation etc. Also check if you are running into deadlocks / infinite loops , exhaustive regex expressions.

One way to help with the analysis is to install application insights sdk to your app. You can then evaluate each API call in detail, and get an understanding of exactly which code took the longest time to execute.

[image: App Insights --> Performance --> (select a operation)-->samples]

App Insights --> Performance --> (select a operation)-->samples